# Java thread-safe class with parameter refreshed every hour

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following class:

```
public class TextSuggester {

    private Suggester suggester;

    public TextSuggester() {
        createSuggester();

    public void refresh() {
        createSuggester();
    }

    private void createSuggester() {
        suggester = new Suggester(File file); // expensive operation
    }    

    public String lookup(String text) {
        return suggester.lookup(text);
    }

}
```

The `lookup` method will be accessed from multiple threads. The `refresh` method will be called every hour and is expensive (takes a long time). My questions are:

1) Is this design thread-safe?

2) If the `lookup` method is called by another thread after `refresh` is called, but before `refresh` returns, will it use the "old" suggester object for the lookup?

If the answer is no to either question, then how do I accomplish what I need? In essence, I want the "old" suggester to be used while the new one is being created.

Comment: Nothing is thread safe right now. Make your field `volatile` and perform the new assignment lazily.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for the quick response. Could you elaborate or post an answer?

Comment: Making your `suggester` field `volatile` will ensure that any thread reading the field will see the latest value written to it by another thread. If a new `Suggester` is being created when `lookup` gets called, then the calling thread will use the most recently written one (the `Suggester` created on the last `refresh` call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is not thread safe. Nothing guarantees that the value of `suggester` seen by thread A within `lookup` will be the same as the value of `suggester` assigned by thread B in `createSuggester`.

What you need to do is add some kind of synchronization so that all changes are visible. Since all your methods are basically just interacting with `suggester`, your *happens before* ordering should be relative to that field. `volatile` is an option. [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) is another.

So either

```
private volatile Suggester suggester; // with standard field access and assignment
```

or

```
private final AtomicReference<Suggester> suggesterRef; // initialized correctly in constructor
...
private void createSuggester() {
    suggesterRef.set(new Suggester(File file));
}
```

until `set` is actually invoked, all other threads calling `get` (in `lookup`) will see the previously assigned value.

Comment: You also mentioned lazy loading in your comment to be used with "volatile". Is that also necessary? Or just making Suggester be volatile is enough?

Comment: @stepanian The lazy loading refers to the fact that the variable or `AtomicReference` will only be set when the new `Suggester` object is fully initialized.

Comment: Got it. So the "volatile" keyword is what is accomplishing the lazy loading, right? Also, just for curiosity, what happens if "volatile" is not used and the thread tries to access "suggester" BEFORE the other thread completes? If it's not the old object, then what? Does it crash?

Comment: @stepanian The assignment to it does. Your `TextSuggester` is itself acting like a reference to a `TextSuggester`.  If `volatile` isn't used, the JVM won't crash. But it's allowed to return the old value or the new value. This is part of the Memory Model of Java and without using `volatile`, there are many possible program orderings. You can read more about `volatile`, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/do-you-ever-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-java).

Comment: Sorry, one last question: If the threads are very short-lived and there is no requirement for them to access the latest suggester object, then would I still need to use "volatile"? Will threads created later eventually access the more recent suggester objects? Thanks.

Comment: @stepanian That's not an easy questions to answer. It depends how you publish the `TextSuggester` instance. _Will threads created later eventually access the more recent suggester objects?_  Yes. Calling `start` on a `Thread` (and thereby creating a thread) [_happens-before any actions in the started thread_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)